# Get names of the variables in an object

Tags: scala

consider the following `object`:

```
class sampleClass { 
  val firstname = "hassan" 
  val lastname = "kachal"
} 

def anotherFunction() { 
   val sampleObj = new sampleClass()
   // here print the list of variables in "sampleObj"
   // I expect to see "firstName" and "lastName" in the output 
}
```

How can I print the name of the variables in an object? (say in the object `sampleObj`, I need to print `firstName` and `lastName` in the output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> sampleObj.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map(f => f.getName)
res3: Array[String] = Array(firstname, lastname)
```

we can use the `Java` `getDeclaredFields` to get all fields in `sampleClass`, you know the `scala` is base on `Java`.

Comment: Any idea how to get the type parameters as well? Say if in the example I had ```val firstname = Option("hassan") val lastname = Option(1)``` one has type `String` and the other has type `Int`. How can I get the type information for each field?